# Finding an object on an arbitrarily large line

Tags: algorithms

There is an arbirarly long line of unknown size. You are standing at a particular point you can either move 1 step forward or 1 step backward. You have to search for an object in that line. Your object can be in any direction. Give an optimal solution.

A search might be 1 step forward, 2 back and so on.

Can you do better than that? What would be an efficient search pattern?

Comment: `arbirarly long line of unknown size` Do you mean a finite segment?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a proof, but strongly suspect it will be hard to beat going to one end of the segment, then turning around and going to the other end.  A good measure of efficiency is the total number of steps taken over all the possible locations of the object.  If you are $a$ from the end in the direction you start out and $b$ from the other end this results in $\frac 12a(a-1)+2ab+\frac 12b(b-1)$, with the first term representing the sums of the distances in the direction you start out, the $2ab$ being the $b$ cases of going $a$ to one end and $a$ back, and the last term the sum of the distances after you get back to start.  You did not specify your strategy after the first three steps, but you have already had one case where you know you will not find the object and presumably have two more to come after you turn around again.

Comment: So you believe this would out perform a bounds doubling strategy like [this one](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/210541/131624)?

Comment: In the problem you link to there is no definition of an optimal solution.  I have given a definition and a calculation of how my algorithm performs.  I suggest you calculate how the competing algorithm performs and compare it.  If you just think about how many steps get retraced you may see the reason I suggested the one I did.  In the one you link to they specify an infinite line, which means you cannot assume a uniform distribution for the object location.  Your question seemed to suppose a finite line of unknown length, so I worked with that.  In that case a uniform distribution makes sense

Comment: I'm satisfied with the simple reasoning of going over already troden ground is a waste when performed once let alone multiple times.  I'm asking because I've been suprized before. I see this pattern holding regardless of the length of the line.

Comment: Regardless of the distribution would it ever make sense to go back over explored ground?

Comment: You have to if you want to get to unexplored ground since you probably start in the middle.  You just want to do it as little as possible.

Comment: Right, but even if it takes forever to find the end isn't the best bet always going to be the unexplored step right infront of you?

Comment: You are moving from the finite to the infinite case.  In the infinite case some zigzag strategy is necessary if you want to be sure of finding the object in finite time.  Please define the question carefully.  Is the line finite or infinite?  If infinite, what is the probability distribution for the object location?  What is the measure of an optimum strategy?  Without a clear question, there cannot be a definite answer.

Comment: I don't mind not finding the object so long as each time I'm asked to decide I can make the best choice.  Expecting to exaustivly search an infinate space seems silly.  My only chance is that the object is at a finite distance.  Given that why should I backtrack?  I might miss the object behind me but if I search 100 steps I might miss 101.  Why waste any steps backtracking?

Comment: If the object is at an infinate distance it it'll be an infinite number of steps to reach it no mater what I do.  If I want a chance at a solution with finite steps I have to accept that the object might be outside that wherever I put it.  Given that, shouldn't I simply make the best use of my moves to maximize the size of my finite space?

Comment: On a finite line you will eventually come to the end.  On an infinite line you will not.  If you just start going in one direction on an infinite line you have $1/2$ chance that you will never find the object.  If you do an expanding zigzag, you will find it in finite time, though that time may be very long.  Do you want the best chance to find it next step, or to be certain to find it eventually?  Either could be considered best.

Comment: I intended that the problem make it imposible to be certain of eventually finding it.  I was aiming to get stratgies that mearly gave you the best odds.  The line doesn't actually have to be infinite.  Just big enough that you never find either end.  Maybe I should have put some kind of a limit on the number of moves.

Comment: Unless you put a limit on the number of steps, you can always search a complete finite line segment.  The zigzag will eventually cover any finite piece of the infinite line, too.  When posing problems like this, the details are very important, so please think carefully about what you want to ask.

Comment: What I wanted was to show your stratgies advantages over the zig zag. You only incure the cost of backtracting once and only once an end has been discovered.  I'm expecting if I charted the effiency of "go to end" vs "zig zag" vs the size of the line that "go to end" would dominate all the way to infinity even if it is 1/2.  If that expectation is wrong I'm hear to find out why.

Comment: @RossMillikan You may want to take a look at OP's previous question yesterday: [Finding an object on an infinite line](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2036894/finding-an-object-on-an-infinite-line). That's what prompted my comment under the main post, which went unanswered.

Comment: @dxiv:  I had the same experience here.  I tried hard to get OP to make the question clear, but failed.

Comment: @RossMillikan this is a fine answer.  But since apparently an infinite causes problems with uniform distribution I wanted to explore what happens when you simply always expand the size of the line to where the player can't exhaustively search it using a finite search.  When the finite search never discovers an end of the line what does that do to the performance? Is it different when the line and search are small vs large?

Comment: Don't want to bait and switch you so I'm willing to ask another question but wanted to be sure I understood enough to form a clear one.